# How to mount Windows shared folder on Redhat

Tags: rhel, windows, file-sharing

Case::

I have to mount the windows shared folder on redhat directory /mnt or anywhere elese.

This is the Windows shared folder Path

**D:\Analytics\Data\DownLoad** This path will be mounted on Redhat so database team can access it.

Please give advice how to do this.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/mount-samba-filesystem-into-rhel-5-5

Comment: or http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23032/mount-a-windows-network-drive

Comment: ok I used this command 
**mount.cifs //10.20.20.158/files /mnt/cifs -o username=umairmustafa,password=mypassword**

and it slapped me with this error 

*mount erro 13=permission denied
refer to mount.cifs(8) manual page(man mount.cifs)* what wrong im doing here

Comment: Are you running that command as root?

Comment: Yes as root. I have seen many tuts but everywhere this command is working but not on mine

Comment: is the share accessible using `smbclient`? you might want to get that working first

Comment: smbclient on Linux or Windows??